# How can I force IE to keep some margin at left in it's browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

My website is properly centered and fitted in all browser windows except the Internet Explorer.
What happens in IE is that it removes the margin from left and forces to align the body left, what I don't want. How can I solve this issue so that the IE can display my site exactly as other browsers do?

If you prefer you can look at the live view [here](http://7seasredovisning.se/) though I am going to paste my code.

:HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>7Seas Redovisning</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>



<body>

<div id="big_wrapper">

<header id="top_header">
<h1><img src="img_akin/7seas.jpeg" id="logo" alt=""/>7Seas Redovisning</h1>
<p><b>

<span class="mob_tele">Mob: 076-9516926 <br />
Tel: 040-133403</span><br />
info@7seasredovisning.se</b>

</p>

</header>

<nav id="top_menu">
<ul>
<li>Intresseanmälan</li>
<li>Öppettider</li>

</ul>

</nav>
<div id="new_div"> <!--only the main content-->
<section id="main_section">
<marquee behavior="alternate">We are coming soon, please check back later.</marquee>

<img src="img_akin/image_1st_body.jpg" id="img1" width="650" height="340" alt=""/>

<ol>
<li>LÖPANDE BÖKFÖRING</li><br />
<li>BOKSLUT & ÅRSREDOVISNING</li><br />
<li>SKATTEDEKLARATION</li><br />
<li>LÖNEADMINISTRATION</li><br />
<li>FAKTURERING</li><br />
<li>INKOMSTDEKLARATION</li><br />
<li>MOMSDEKLARATION</li><br />
<li>BOLAGSBILDNING</li><br />
<li>EKONOMI KONSLUT</li><br />

</ol>


</section>


</div>

<footer id="the_footer">
<ul>
<li>
© 7 seas Redovisning <br />                                         

En del av 7seas Money Transfer KB<br />                 
F-skatt registrerat  <br />                                         
Org, Nr: 969756-4079 <br />   
SEB Företagskonto: 5502-1030132<br />
BG: 102-5006

</li>



<li>
Besökadress: Skomakarebyn 8E<br /> 
218 41 Bunkeflostrand<br /> 
Malmö, Sweden <br />  
Follow us on FB <!-- SMARTADDON BEGIN -->
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async = true;
s.src='http://s1.smartaddon.com/share_addon.js';
var j =document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];j.parentNode.insertBefore(s,j);
})();
</script>


<a href="http://www.smartaddon.com/?share" title="Share Button" onclick="return sa_tellafriend('www.7seasredovisning.se','bookmarks')"><img alt="Share" src="http://s1.smartaddon.com/s8.png" border="0" /></a>

                        <br /><i>Design & Development: DH BANGLADESH in SWEDEN</i>

</li>


<li>
Tel: 040-133403<br />
Mob: 076-9516926<br />
e-Mail: info@7seasredovisning.se<br/>
www.7seasredovisning.se<br/>
<span id="webstat">
<script src="http://stats.webstat.se/assets/stat_isp2.php"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("<" + "script src=\"http://stats.webstat.se/statCounter.asp?id=38356&size=" + screen.width + "x" + screen.height + "&depth=" + screen.colorDepth + "&referer=" + escape(document.referrer) + "&isp=" + info2+ "\"></" + "script>"); 
-->
</script>
</span>
<!-- Slut WEBSTAT.SE kod -->

</li>

</ul>


</footer>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

.CSS:

```
    *{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
#top_header h1 {

font:bold 40px Prisoner SF;
margin-top:-20px;
color:#006400;


}
#top_header p {

margin-top:-100px;

color:#A0522D;
float:right;
font-family:Euphemia;
}

.mob_tele{
font-size:12.5px;
}

h2{

font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
header,section,footer,aside,nav,article,hgroup{
display:block;

}
body{
width:100%;
display:-webkit-box;
display:-o-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-ms-box-pack:center;
-o-box-pack:center;
background-color:#E6E6FA;


}


#big_wrapper{
max-width:1200px;
margin-top:20px;


display:-webkit-box;
display:-o-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-moz-box-orient:vertical;
-ms-box-orient:vertical;
box-flex:1;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
-moz-box-flex:1;
-ms-box-flex:1;
background-color:white;


}
#top_header{

border:3px soild gray;
padding:20px;

}
#logo{
padding-top:20px;

}

#top_menu{
border: 2px solid #20B2AA;
border-radius:4px;
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #87CEEB, #C0C0C0, #87CEEB);
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #87CEEB, #C0C0C0, #87CEEB);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #87CEEB, #C0C0C0, #87CEEB);
background:-ms-linear-gradient(to bottom, #87CEEB, #C0C0C0, #87CEEB);
background:-o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #87CEEB, #C0C0C0, #87CEEB);



/*background:#8FBC8F;*/
color:black;
}
#top_menu li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
padding:7px;
font:bold 18px Euphemia;
float:right;
margin-right:50px;

}



#new_div{
display:block;
display:-moz-box;
display:-o-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
-moz-box-orient:horizontal;
-ms-box-orient:horizontal;

}

#main_section{
/*
border: 1px solid blue;
*/
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-ms-box-flex: 1;
-o-box-flex: 1;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 20px;


/*
float: left;

width: calc(75% - 82px);
*/

}
#main_section li{
margin-left:255px;
font-family:Euphemia;
background-image:url(img/backgrounds.jpg) no-repeat;
font-weight:bold;

}
#main_section marquee{

font-family:Segoe Print;
font-size:40px;
font-weight:bold;
margin-bottom:40px;
color:#B22222;

}




#img1{
float:right;
}


#the_footer{
/*
text-align:center;
*/
background:#F0F8FF;
/*
padding:20px;
*/
border-top:2px solid green;
}
#the_footer li{
list-style:none;
display:inline-block;
padding:40px;
margin-left:35px;
font-family:Euphemia;
font-size:13px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of -ms-box, try this:

```
body {
   display:-ms-flexbox;
   -ms-flex-pack:center;
   -ms-flex-align:center;
}
```

This works for IE10+.

Comment: You are a pro my friend Deimoks, hats off! It helps perfect. I thanks you a lot.